# How do I stop my heatmap from flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching, flicker

I am making a page that displays data in the form of a heatmap. The script that writes the image to the page runs every second. As I am plotting from live data, it's very important that the heatmap updates every second.

The problem is that my image flickers. How can I get rid of that flicker?

I can't cache it as I need to change it. If the image flickering cannot be stopped, can it be given some smooth transition?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function toggle (mainImage, backupImage) {
    //$("#imagecontainer").load("./php/sarimage.png");

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById(mainImage);
    var imageEle = document.getElementById(backupImage);
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    var source ="./php/sarimage.png?dummy=";
     source = source.concat(randomnumber);
            imageEle.src = source;
    $("#imagecontainer").load(source);
    ele.src= imageEle.src;
    }, 1000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The flicker is in how it's being updated now, which is relevant info to post.

Comment: No. AJAX might "get the data" (which might be some HTML). That's now how the *element* is updated.

Comment: i dint exactly understand what u meant!! can you elaborate pls

Comment: How are you replacing the image in the IMG element or replacing the IMG element?

Comment: oh the script echoes the html every second!! since the browser was caching the image i added a random number to the img src which tricks the browser to think its a new image and it reloads it. The location of the image never changes gnuplot just keeps on overwriting it every second.

Comment: Here are things to try: In a hidden IMG (or Image object), request the new URI. Then in that IMG's 'onload' event, set the target of the visible IMG or swap in the hidden IMG. Then there will be no flicker as the new image is being downloaded.

Comment: thanks it kinda works.Though it flickers once a while which i dont know why. Also, browser sometimes caches the image but that is rare. I added code to my question if you see any obvious errors please point it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @pst: that's not a good solution, as some browsers don't load images until they go on screen(although that's usually on embedded)

Comment: @trailblazer the caching is probably happening because you are getting the same random number as you did a few seconds ago. instead of random why not try `Date().getTime()`

Comment: @Dani Have a better solution? Post as an answer :)

Comment: @James - thanks that fixed the caching problem. The only issue right now is while the page is opened the image crashes sometimes and the browser is not able to retrieve it until i refresh it. Any thoughts on how can fix this?

Comment: @trailblazer What do you mean by "it chrashes"? if you mean you get a http error. Put in an error callback to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're feeding a `SRC` URL to the image using JavaScript that runs an AJAX call once a second to get fresh data.  I suspect that the image is probably flickering because of network latency -- it takes a moment for the fresh image data to download and then get updated.

You might try introducing a one-second delay into the script.  Use two images, one on screen for the currently displayed data, and one offscreen.  Load fresh info into the off screen image.  Then, swap the positions of the two images (onscreen goes off, offscreen goes on).  Because the fresh data would be loaded into an image outside the viewport, the download wouldn't happen visibly.  Just moving it into position should take place with no perceptible flicker.

It would go something like this (this is pseudo code that won't necessarily run).  First, some HTML -- just a couple of images.

```
<img src="initial.png" alt="heatmap" class="heatmap onscreen" />
<img src="loading-area.png" alt="heatmap" class="heatmap" />
```

Then some CSS:

```
/* By default heatmaps are off screen. */
.heatmap { position: absolute; left: -999em; }

/* But then we override that for ones marked as on screen. */
.heatmap.onscreen { position: static; left: auto; }
```

Lastly some JavaScript.

```
var firstRun = true;

function loadNewImage(){
    // Download fresh image and load it into an image OFF SCREEN.
    var imagePath = '/path/to/image.png?dummy='+Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    $(".heatmap:not(.onscreen)").attr("src", "imagePath");
}

function updateImage(){
    if(firstRun){
        // The first time this function runs, load new data ...
        loadNewImage();

        // Now make a note that the function has run already.
        firstRun = false;

        // And return without doing anything else.
        return false;
    } else {
        // The off screen image has fresh data by this time.  Swap it.
        $(".heatmap:not(.onscreen)").addClass("next");

        // Remove the onscreen class from the current image, so it
        // moves off screen.
        $(".onscreen").removeClass("onscreen");

        // Add onscreen to the next one, moving it into place.
        $(".next").addClass("onscreen");

        // Remove the "next" class from the newly displayed image.
        $(".next").removeClass("next");

        // Load more image data.
        loadNewImage();
    }

    // Lastly, call this same function again in a second.
    window.setTimeout(updateImage, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Start the swapping.
    updateImage();
});
```

Assuming you have a reasonably speedy and reliable connection, something like that should take care of flickering caused by network latency.  It does introduce a one second delay -- the currently displayed image will always be one second behind realtime.  But if real time synchronicity is important to you, then HTML/CSS/JavaScript is probably the wrong tool for the job.

If there's some OTHER cause for your flickering, well, good luck.